# Concat multiple IEnumerables with constraint

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I have an object with multiple Offers assigned through different ways. An Offer is exactly for one Product and an object has multiple Offers. Now I want all Offers of an object following a specifig business logic that a Product is contained only once.

At the moment I have implemented it as follows:

```
List<Offer> offers = new List<Offer>();
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();                
this.AddOffersToList(offers, products, ov.Offers.Where(o => o.OfferType == composedOffer));
this.AddOffersToList(offers, products, ov.Offers.Where(o => o.OfferType == simpleOffer));
this.AddOffersToList(offers, products, ov.ComposedOfferList.Offers);
this.AddOffersToList(offers, products, ov.SimpleOfferList.Offers);
```

AddOffersToList method:

```
private void AddOffersToList(List<Offer> offers, List<Product> products,IEnumerable<Offer> newOffers)
{
    foreach (Offer offer in newOffers)
    {
        // add offer only if the product is not contained yet
        if (!products.Contains(offer.Product))
        {
            offers.Add(offer);
            products.Add(offer.Product);
        } 
    }
}
```

This seems to be not the most elegant and performance way. The "constraints" are the order of AddOffersToList method calls and that the Product is contained once only.

Anything that helps me solve this problem better is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is 'equivalent' to what you have I believe.

```
var offers = ov.Offers.Where(o => o.OfferType == composedOffer)
    .Concat(ov.Offers.Where(o => o.OfferType == simpleOffer))
    .Concat(ov.ComposedOfferList.Offers)
    .Concat(ov.SimpleOfferList.Offers)
    .GroupBy(offer => offer.Product)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();

var products = offers.Select(offer => offer.Product).ToList();
```

Comment: I think this code does not take the order into account. If I have Product x in ov.Offers.Where(o => o.OfferType == composedOffer) but also in let's say ov.SimpleOfferList.Offers it is very important that the Offer in the first result is taken.

Comment: After writing unit tests I was able to prove that your code is doing what I want. Thanks a lot! :)